# How to export target's properties when installing targets in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have the following sample project which I would like to export `PROTOCOLS_LIST` properties.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.0)
project(exported_props LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(protocols ...)
set_target_properties(protocols PROPERTIES PROTOCOLS_LIST "IP" "TCP" "UDP")

install(TARGETS protocols EXPORT protocol)
install(EXPORT protocol DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

When installing the above sample code, the created `protocol.cmake` file will not contain my custom property `PROTOCOLS_LIST`.

Is it possible to pass some target's properties when installing TARGETS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, CMake installs only specific set of target's properties.

For tell CMake to install additional properties you could list that properties in the [EXPORT_PROPERTIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXPORT_PROPERTIES.html) target's property:

```
# Tell CMake to install PROTOCOLS_LIST property for the target.
set_property(TARGET protocols APPEND PROPERTY EXPORT_PROPERTIES PROTOCOLS_LIST)
```